# Calculating the coefficient of $x^{12}$

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following function:

$$ f(x)=\frac{x^{2}+x+2}{(1-x^{2})^{3}} $$

I'm trying to calculate the coefficient of $x^{12}$. I usully use the [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) to solve this problem.

First thing that comes to mind, is to do the following:

$$\frac{x^{2}+x+2}{(1-x^{2})^{3}} = (x^2+x+2)\cdot \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}{r+2 \choose r}x^{2r} $$

But what can I do with $x^2+x+2$?

Comment: Just write out three separate sums. Take the term corresponding to $r = 10$ together with $x^2$, the term corresponding to $r = 11$ with $x$ and the term for $r = 12$ for $2$.

Comment: In fact, it's easy to see that $x$ in the denominator will give rise only to odd powers in the power series, so that will contribute $0$. Considering the contributions of $x^2+2$ yields $\binom{(6-1)+2}{2}+2\binom{6+2}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

First express $f(x)$ as the sum of six partial fractions. Next find their 12-th derivative, it is not difficult. Finally calculate $f^{(12)}(0)/12!$ which is the coefficent of $x^{12}$.

Comment: For the partial fraction decomposition, ask [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E%7B2%7D%2Bx%2B2%7D%7B(1-x%5E%7B2%7D)%5E%7B3%7D%7D).

Comment: I think this is the hard way. The comment from T. Bongers gives a much easier way.